# Odoo 13 error in xml file while upgrading the module

Tags: odoo

I am getting this error while upgrading my custom module in odoo13 while upgrading it , the error is within this xml file.

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/gunalan_demo/views/views.xml", line 31
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: form line 9 and field, line 31, column 16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>

    <record id ="request_form" model ="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">view.demo.form</field>
      <field name="model">car.request</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string ="Car Request Form">
          <sheet>
            <div class="oe_title">
              <label for="name" class="oe_title_only"/>
              <h1>
                <field name="name" placeholder="Request Demo"/>
                </h1>
            </div>  
            <group>
              <group>
                  <field name="date_from"/>
                  <field name="date_to"/>
              </group>
              <group>
                <field name="emplyoee_id"/>
                <field name="car_id"/>

              </group>  
            </group>


          </sheet>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id='request_tree' model='ir.ui.view' >
        <field name='name'>view.demo.tree</field>
        <field name='model'>car.request</field>
        <field name='arch' type='xml'>
            <tree string='Car Request Tree'>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="emplyoee_id"/>
                <field name="car_id"/>
                <field name="date_from"/>
                <field name="date_to"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_request_views" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Car Request</field>
      <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
      <field name="res_model">car.request</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
          Car Request
        </p><p>
          Click here to add
        </p>
      </field>
    </record>

    <!-- This Menu Item will appear in the Upper bar, That's why It needs NO parent or action -->
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request_root" name="Car Request" sequence="10"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request_categ" name="Car Request" parent="menu_car_request_root" sequence="1"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request" name="Car Request" parent="menu_car_request_categ" action="action_request_views" sequence="1"/>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the error message is already telling you everything? You've opened the `form` tag but never closed it.